MultipleObjectsReturned at /editar-acumulado/2/ get() returned more than one Acumulado -- it returned 3
In my Django project, I have the next code:
@login_required
def editar_acumulado(request, estudiante_id):
    estudiante = Estudiante.objects.get(id=estudiante_id)
    grupo_clase = estudiante.matriculas.first().grupoclase
    asignatura = grupo_clase.asignatura  # Obtener la asignatura registrada en el grupo de clase del estudiante

    try:
        acumulado = Acumulado.objects.get(estudiante=estudiante, asignatura=asignatura)
    except Acumulado.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(request, 'Debes registrar los acumulados en "0" para este estudiante antes de registrar sus acumulados.')
        return redirect('RegistroCalificaciones', grupo_clase_id=grupo_clase.id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditAcumuladoForm(request.POST, instance=acumulado)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Acumulado actualizado con éxito')
            return redirect('RegistroCalificaciones', grupo_clase_id=grupo_clase.id)
    else:
        form = EditAcumuladoForm(instance=acumulado)

    return render(request, 'PanelDocentes/PortalNotas.html', {'form': form, 'estudiante': estudiante})

will also leave my form code here:
class EditAcumuladoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Acumulado
        fields = ('parcial', 'asignatura', 'semestre', 'AnioEscol', 'Nota1', 'Nota2', 'Nota3', 'Nota4', 'Nota5', 'Examen')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        estudiante = kwargs.pop('estudiante', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if estudiante:
            matricula_grupo = estudiante.matriculas.first()
            grupo_clase = matricula_grupo.grupoclase
            self.fields['asignatura'].queryset = Asignatura.objects.filter(id=grupo_clase.asignatura.id)

        self.fields['parcial'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self._set_attributes('Nota1', 'Nota2', 'Nota3', 'Nota4', 'Nota5', min_value=0, max_value=20)
        self._set_attributes('Examen', min_value=0, max_value=40)

        self.fields['semestre'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Semestre.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        self.fields['AnioEscol'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AnioEscolar.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

        self.fields['suma_notas'] = forms.CharField(label='Total Acumulados', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'class': 'form-control'}))
        self.fields['suma_total'] = forms.CharField(label='Nota Final', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'class': 'form-control'}))

        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            Nota1 = instance.Nota1 if instance.Nota1 is not None else 0
            Nota2 = instance.Nota2 if instance.Nota2 is not None else 0
            Nota3 = instance.Nota3 if instance.Nota3 is not None else 0
            Nota4 = instance.Nota4 if instance.Nota4 is not None else 0
            Nota5 = instance.Nota5 if instance.Nota5 is not None else 0
            Examen = instance.Examen if instance.Examen is not None else 0

            suma_notas = Nota1 + Nota2 + Nota3 + Nota4 + Nota5
            suma_total = suma_notas + Examen

            self.fields['suma_notas'] = forms.CharField(label='Total Acumulados', initial=suma_notas, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'class':'form-control'}))
            self.fields['suma_total'] = forms.CharField(label='Nota Final', initial=suma_total, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'class':'form-control'}))

            if suma_total == 60:
                for field_name in ['Nota1', 'Nota2', 'Nota3', 'Nota4', 'Nota5']:
                    field = self.fields[field_name]
                    if field.initial == None:
                        field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
                        field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' disabled'

    def _set_attributes(self, *fields, min_value=None, max_value=None):
        for field in fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            if min_value is not None:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['min'] = min_value
            if max_value is not None:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['max'] = max_value

models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from datetime import date

#=======================TABLE USER STATUS=======================
class Estado(models.Model):
    estado = [
        ('Activo','Activo'), 
        ('Inactivo', 'Inactivo'), 
    ]
    Estados = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=estado, blank=True, null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Estados}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Estados"



#=======================TABLA SECCION=======================
class Seccion(models.Model):
    secciones = [
        ('A', 'A'),
        ('B', 'B'),
        ('C', 'C'),
        ('D', 'D'),
    ]
    SeccionNivel = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=secciones, blank=True, null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.SeccionNivel}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Secciones"



#=======================TABLA GRADOS=======================
class Grado(models.Model):
    CodigoGrado = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    grados = [
        ('1ro', '1ro'), ('2do', '2do'), ('3ro', '3ro'),
        ('4to', '4to'), ('5to', '5to'), ('6to', '6to'),
        ('7mo', '7mo'), ('8vo', '8vo'), ('9no', '9no'),
        ('10mo','10mo'), ('11mo','11mo')
        
    ]
    GradoNivel = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=grados, blank=True, null=True)
    seccion = models.ForeignKey(Seccion, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True,null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.CodigoGrado}, {self.GradoNivel}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Grados"


#=======================TABLA ASIGNATURAS===================
class Asignatura(models.Model):
    CodigoAsigantura = models.CharField(max_length=6, default="codigo")
    nombreAsignatura = [
        ('Lengua y Literatura', 'Lengua y Literatura'), 
        ('Lengua Extranjera','Lengua Extranjera'),
        ('Creciendo en Valores','Creciendo en Valores'),
        ('Conociendo mi Mundo','Conociendo mi Mundo'),
        ('Derecho y Dignidad de la Mujer','Derecho y Dignidad de la Mujer'),
        ('Educación Física','Educación Física'),
        ('Aprender Emprender y Prosperar','Aprender Emprender y Prosperar'),
        ('Estudios Sociales','Estudios Sociales'),
        ('Talleres de Arte y Cultura','Talleres de Arte y Cultura'),
        ('Ciencias Naturales','Ciencias Naturales'),
        ('Biología','Biología'),
        ('Matemática','Matemática'), 
        ('Física','Física'),
        ('Química','Química'),
        ('Computación','Computación')
        
    ]
    asignatura = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=nombreAsignatura, blank=True, null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.CodigoAsigantura}, {self.asignatura}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Asignaturas"



#=======================TABLA ESTUDIANTES=======================
class Estudiante(models.Model):
    Nombres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CodigoEstudiantil = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    FechaRegistro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Nombres} {self.Apellidos}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Estudiantes"



#=======================TABLA ANIO ESCOLAR===================
class AnioEscolar(models.Model):
    anio = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=date.today().year)
    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.anio}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Año Escolar"



#=======================TABLA PARCIALES=======================
class Parciales(models.Model):
    parciales = [
        ('I Parcial','I Parcial'),
        ('II Parcial','II Parcial'),
        ('III Parcial','III Parcial'),
        ('IV Parcial','IV Parcial')
    ]
    parcial = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=parciales, blank=True, null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.parcial}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Parciales"



class Semestre(models.Model):
    CodigoSemestre = models.CharField(max_length=3, default="semestre")
    sem = [
        ('I Semestre','I Semestre'),
        ('II Semestre','II Semestre')
    ]
    semestreNivel = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=sem, blank=True, null=True)
    parcial = models.ForeignKey(Parciales, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True,null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.CodigoSemestre}, {self.semestreNivel}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Semestres"



#=======================TABLA NOTA ACUMULADO=======================
class Acumulado(models.Model):
    Nota1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Nota2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Nota3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Nota4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Nota5 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Examen = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    actividad = models.TextField()
    asignatura = models.ForeignKey(Asignatura, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    parcial = models.ForeignKey(Parciales, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    semestre = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    AnioEscol = models.ForeignKey(AnioEscolar, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default="")

     #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.estudiante}, {self.Nota1}, {self.Nota2}, {self.Nota3}, {self.Nota4}, {self.Nota5}, {self.Examen}, {self.asignatura.CodigoAsigantura}, {self.semestre.CodigoSemestre}, {self.parcial.parcial}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Acumulados"


#=======================TABLA NOTAS=======================
class Nota(models.Model):
    NotaCualitativa = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    NotaCuantitativa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    Fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    asignatura = models.ForeignKey(Asignatura, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    acumulado = models.ForeignKey(Acumulado, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    parcial = models.ForeignKey(Parciales, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    semestre = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Notas"


#=======================TABLA USUARIOS=======================
class User(AbstractUser):
    CodigoUser = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    rol = [
        ('Administrador','Administrador'),
        ('Asistente','Asistente'),
        ('Docente','Docente')
    ]
    Rol = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=rol, blank=True, null=True)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}, {self.CodigoUser}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Usuarios"



#=======================TABLA GRUPOS DE CLASES=======================
class GrupoClase(models.Model):
    CodigoGrupo = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    NombreGrupo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    FechaInicio = models.DateField(null=False)
    FechaFin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    grado = models.ForeignKey(Grado, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seccion = models.ForeignKey(Seccion, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    docente = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    asignatura = models.ForeignKey(Asignatura, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    anio = models.ForeignKey(AnioEscolar, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    semestre = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.NombreGrupo}, {self.docente}, {self.asignatura}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Grupos De Clases"
    
    def generate_codigo_grupo(self):
        return f"{self.grado.CodigoGrado}{self.seccion}-{self.asignatura.CodigoAsigantura}-{self.semestre.CodigoSemestre}{self.anio.anio}"
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Siempre generar un nuevo código al guardar
        self.CodigoGrupo = self.generate_codigo_grupo()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)



#=======================TABLA MATRICULA ESTUDIANTES A GRUPO DE CLASE=======================
class MatriculaGrupo(models.Model):
    grupoclase = models.ForeignKey(GrupoClase, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='matriculas')
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    #Mostrar propiedades en el admin django.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.grupoclase}, {self.estudiante}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Matriculas Grupos"
    


#=======================TABLA BOLETA ACADÉMICA=======================
class BoletaAcademica(models.Model):
    CodigoBoleta = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    NoBoleta = models.IntegerField()
    FechaBoleta = models.DateTimeField()
    grado = models.ForeignKey(Grado, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seccion = models.ForeignKey(Seccion, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    asignatura = models.ForeignKey(Asignatura, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    docente = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    nota = models.ForeignKey(Nota, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    semestre = models.ForeignKey(Semestre, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    anio = models.ForeignKey(AnioEscolar, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=date.today().year)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Boletas Académicas"

It works correctly when the student has grades in only one subject according to his class group, but when the student has grades in different subjects I get an error.
The error I get is MultipleObjectsReturned which occurs because the query Accumulated.objects.get(student=student, subject=subject) returns more than one Accumulated object. This is because there are several Accumulated objects that meet the condition of having the same student and subject.
